# Wikipedia api to get the jpeg image from wikipage

Tags: image, media, mediawiki, wikipedia-api

I want to make an app for which i need to extract wikipedi images from api. But some page contain also the .png image. for my code I only need the .jpeg image. I found this api https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&generator=images&iiurlwidth=400&generator=images&titles=Kiel by which I get jpeg ang png both. How can I send request only for jpeg image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API does not support that kind of request, you will have to sort that out on your side. For an easy overview of what you can do, use the API Sandbox. Here is a query with your parameters but in the sandbox: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&prop=imageinfo&format=json&iiprop=url&iiurlwidth=400&titles=Kiel&generator=images